# User home folder points to SYSTEM32 folder after runas

Tags: windows

I have a problem running `runas /USER:testuser cmd` or `runas /USER:testuser powershell`:

1. If testuser has opened RDP session, %HOMEPATH% points to \Users\testuser
2. If testuser is logged off, the environment looks strange to me:

   ```
   PS C:\Windows\system32> echo $env:HOMEPATH
   \Windows\system32
   PS C:\Windows\system32> echo $env:APPDATA
   C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming
   PS C:\Windows\system32> echo $env:USERPROFILE
   C:\Users\testuser
   PS C:\Windows\system32> cd ~
   PS C:\Windows\system32> cd $home
   PS C:\Windows\system32>
   ```

I need a correct %HOMEPATH% for my scheduled script. Is it expected behaviour? What can I do about that?

I've tested it on two Win2008, Win7, Win2012 with the same result.

UPDATE: The initial issue was a hanging scheduled task. When I had tested it with runas, I found that ssh command doesn't see a configuration placed in user directory and asks user for additional info.

Comment: HOMEPATH is legacy technology, what are you using it for?

Comment: I've updated the post. My scheduled script cannot find a user config files (gpg, git, ssh) and it looks like %HOMEPATH% variable is responsible for that.

Comment: Well, it's just an environment variable.  Your script can set it to whatever it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned ssh, I'm going to take a stab at an answer, since I just worked through a similar issue. I'm using cwRsync 3.1.0, and the example script that comes packaged with it uses %HOMEPATH% to setup %HOME% for rsync execution. Like you experienced, when using 'runas' with the target user not logged into the host, the script halts to accept a hostid, because Windows\system32.ssh doesn't exist. The HOMEPATH is set to Windows\system32.

When the target user is logged into the host (but runas is run under a distinct user's login), the HOMEPATH is set to user's profile path (Users\), and the .ssh path does resolve.

My solution was to change the script o use %USERPROFILE%, rather than %HOMEPATH%. At https://serverfault.com/questions/29948/difference-between-profile-and-home-path and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions.aspx there is discussion that to my understanding, indicates %HOMEPATH% is for user content, whereas %USERPROFILE% is for settings, etc., and probably better for pointing to .ssh.